# How to resolve sqlmap error: [CRITICAL] page not found (404)

Tags: sqlmap

I'm currently testing my own website with SQLMap, every time when I want to enter the URL this comes up:

```
[*] starting @ 19:26:01 /2023-07-24/

[19:26:02] [INFO] testing connection to the target URL
[19:26:02] [CRITICAL] page not found (404)
it is not recommended to continue in this kind of cases. Do you want to quit and make sure that everything is set up properly? [Y/n] 
[19:26:02] [WARNING] HTTP error codes detected during run:
404 (Not Found) - 1 times

[*] ending @ 19:26:02 /2023-07-24/
```

- Command I used: `sqlmap -u 'http://examplepage/page.php?i5d='`
- I expected that it connects to the URL to run some tests with it.
- I thank everyone in forward for answers, thank you :)

Comment: does the url work when you point a browser at it?

Comment: How do I point a browser to it?

Comment: enter 'http://examplepage/page.php?i5d=' into the browser address bar